# How to solve HTTP Error 500 in Phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, linux, apache

Apache error log says:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/core.lib.php on line 235

I'm running Debian 8.7

Comment: what version of PhpMyAdmin are you running? https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4557/

Comment: Moved error into quote

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext`

then restart your server

`sudo service apache2 restart`